# what is wrong with this code of nltk python

Tags: python, nltk

```
def ethos(file):
    f = open(file)
    raw = f.read()
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
    words_to_match = ['love' , 'good' , 'excellent' , 'perfect' , 'brilliant' , 'easy' , 'well' , 'made' , 'impressive' , 'great']
    matching_tokens = []
    for tokens in tokens:
        if tokens in words_to_match:
            matching_tokens.append(tokens)
            return matching_tokens
```

I am not able to understand why this code is not able to return a list, its just returning one token/word, after execution

Comment: ... bad title, worse question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `return` statement is in the loop, which means that the function immediately returns as soon as `tokens in words_to_match` is true. To correct this problem, just move the `return` out of the loop, like this: (for simplicity I removed the part of opening a file. It's just a test. You'll have to let your method read that file)

```
import nltk

def ethos():
    raw = 'i love well made products'
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
    words_to_match = ['love' , 'good' , 'excellent' , 'perfect' , 'brilliant' , 'easy' , 'well' , 'made' , 'impressive' , 'great']
    matching_tokens = []
    for tokens in tokens:
        if tokens in words_to_match:
            matching_tokens.append(tokens)
    return matching_tokens

print ethos()
```

the result is

```
['love', 'well', 'made']
```

It seems to work

Comment: I tried this, but the result is same/

Comment: and it'd be helpful to know what value `tokens` had before the loop

Comment: see i converted a text file into tokens and then want to have all the tokens those which match with the matching tokens list.

Comment: I know what the program is supposed to do. It would be helpful if you gave concrete examples of what is going wrong. Just a sample `raw`, what you expected, and what you actually get

Comment: I am getting this ['well'] and I want a list like ['good' , 'love' , 'suitable' , .........]

Comment: are you sure your input file contains not only `well`, but also  `good`, `love`, etc.?

Comment: thankyou, it worked for me. I did not realize that I needed to put the return statement out of the loop